# Prioritize computers/traffic on a home network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, skype

I have a Cisco EA2700 router hooked up to a Thompson DCM476 modem in my home network. There is one user on a mac that hosts Skype and google hangout calls on a nightly basis and whenever this happens the network almost slows to a stall. Other users can barely just check their email and or use play online games. It takes about 8-10 seconds just to load a webpage.

Is there some way to setup a limit on this computer so he doesn't consume the entire bandwidth?

So far I've tried using the Media Prioritization app provided with the router but it doesn't seem to help at all.

Comment: Standard warning: Whenever talking about bandwidth usage on wireless, be sure to look at airtime usage, not typical bandwidth measures like the number of bits or bytes moved. The fastest 802.11ac devices can move data at 1300mbps. Any device could move data at as slow as 6 or even 1mbps under bad conditions. You really can't tell who your airtime hog is by just looking at who is moving the most bits or bytes. You have to look at what PHY (signaling) rate they are using while moving those bits, and thus calculate how much airtime they're hogging.